# Find $\angle BOD$ in the given figure.

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider a circle with centre $O$. Two chords $AB$ and $CD$ extended intersect at a point $P$ outside the circle. If $\angle AOC=43^\circ$ and $\angle BPD=18^\circ$, then the value of $\angle BOD$ is ____?

[image: Given Image]

Assuming that $AB=CD$ I have been able to deduce that it will be $7^\circ$. How to do the sum without the extra assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw $AD$.  Then
$$ \angle BOD = 2\angle BAD = 2\angle PAD = 2(\angle ADC-\angle APD) = \angle AOC-2\angle APD = 7^\circ $$

Comment: Very efficient, +1

Comment: Yeah--my method is wrong: I downloaded the pic. and checked on paint whether OBC is a straight line or not. It isn't, and so I have deleted my post.

Comment: Fantastic, it is just majestic,+1

Answer (score 0):

Answer: $\angle BOD=7^o$

Proof:
Look at the triangle OAC. Then $\angle OAC=\angle OCA=\frac{137}{2}$.

Now, look at the triangle APC. Then  $\angle OAP+ \angle OCP+137+18=180$. This implies that $\angle OAP+ \angle OCP=25^o$.

Look at the quadrilateral ABDC which is inscribed in a circle. Hence  $180^o=\angle B+  \angle C=\angle OBA+ \angle OBD+\angle OCP+\frac{137}{2}=$

$\angle OAP+ \angle OBD+\angle OCP+\frac{137}{2}$. This implies that $\angle OBD=180-25-\frac{137}{2}$. Hence $\angle BOD=180-2\angle OBD=7^o$.